# jqGrid in Web Forms does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jqgrid

I would appreciate if someone could help me with the following, I have a grid jqGrid not load my javascript, as defined in trirand, it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'jqGrid.asmx/getDat',
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { key: true, label: 'ID', name: 'id', width: 55 },
            { label: 'Name', name: 'name', width: 250 },
            { label: 'Address', name: "address", width: 250 }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        loadonce: true,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
});
```

And my WebMethod defined in a Web service, is as follows:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getDat()
    {
            List<dat> li = new List<dat>();
            li.Add(new dat() { id = "12001", name = "name 1", address = "address 1" });
            li.Add(new dat() { id = "12002", name = "name 2", address = "address 2" });
            li.Add(new dat() { id = "14021", name = "name 3", address = "address 3" });

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(li);
    }
```

Fails to enter the WebMethod

firebug message is:

Unrecognized application form

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code you should do the following:

1. you should change the type of returned value from `string` to `object`
2. change the line `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(li);` to `return li;`

It should fix your main problem.

Additionally you can consider to *remove* the column `id` from `colModel` if you don't need to show it to the server. The default option `jsonReader: { id: "id" }` of jqGrid will force reading of `id` property of the items of input data and use the value as rowid (the `id` attribute of every `<tr>` elements of the grid).

I would recommend you to verify which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use. I'd recommend you to use the latest version 4.13.1 of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which you can download [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases), uses from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs), install from npm, NuGet or bower (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)).

Answer (score 0):

Oleg Thanks for responding, I made the suggested changes, but I get the same error, fails to enter the Web Service, something else is missing me.

I'm using version 5.0.0.0 (Feb, 5th, 2016) obtained from http://www.trirand.net/, I have also tried the version indicas me, just does not get to run, use Visual Studio 2013 framework 4.5

Thanks again.